# SemanticUI: passing search results from one search to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, semantic-ui

This is my script A:

```
$("div[id^='search_awsaccountids_']").search({
  apiSettings: {
    url: '/v1/aws-suggestions?accountids_prefix={query}',
    fullTextSearch: true
  },
  fields: {
    results : 'aws_account_ids',
    title   : 'accountid',
    type   : 'result'
  },
  minCharacters : 1,
  fullTextSearch: true
});
```

I want the output of above script `A` to be passed in the url in script `B`:

```
$("div[id^='search_iamroles_']").search({
// $("#search_iamroles_").search({
  fullTextSearch: true,
  apiSettings: {
    url: '/v1/aws-suggestions?accountid=<value_here_from_above>&iamroles_prefix={query}'
  },
  fields: {
    results : 'iam_roles',
    title   : 'iamrole',
    type   : 'result'
  },
  minCharacters : 1
});
```

I tried `beforeSend` could not get that working, also tried creating the URL, thinking it will replace at runtime based on the output:

```
url: "/v1/aws-suggestions?accountid=" + $("#search_awsaccountids_view_roles").val() + "&iamroles_prefix={query}"
```

This is my form.

```
      <div class="ui medium form">
        <div class="two column row">
          <div id="search_awsaccountids_view_roles" class="ui search">
            <label><strong>Account Id</strong></label>
            <input class="prompt" placeholder="Aws account id" type="text">
          </div>
          <h3></h3>
          <div id="search_iamroles_view_roles" class="ui search">
            <label><strong>IAM Role Name</strong></label>
            <input class="prompt" placeholder="demo role" type="text">
          </div>
          <h3></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any pointers, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, this helped: [Semantic UI - Getting search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630133/semantic-ui-getting-search-query)

```
  $("div[id^='search_iamroles_']").search({
  // $("#search_iamroles_").search({
    fullTextSearch: true,
    apiSettings: {
      url: "/v1/aws-suggestions?" + "&iamroles_prefix={query}",
      beforeSend: function(settings) {
        settings.data = "accountid=" + document.getElementById('inputValue').value;
        return settings;
    }
    },
    fields: {
       results : 'iam_roles',
      title   : 'iamrole',
      type   : 'result'
    },
    minCharacters : 1
  });
```